# Github pages not recognizing idex.html

Tags: github-pages

Going to https://jkarimi91.github.io throws a 404 error. However, going to https://jkarimi91.github.io/index loads the homepage i.e. `index.html` just fine. Why is https://jkarimi91.github.io not fetching `index.html`?

The site files can be found at https://github.com/jkarimi91/jkarimi91.github.io

Comment: Here all of those links work just fine

Comment: Weird, I guess github pages takes quite a bit of time to process all the files; I was receiving 404 errors on the homepage for ~1 hour but now it seems to be fine. Thanks for letting me know. Any thoughts?

Comment: Local cache issue on your browser? (Ie did you reproduce it with another Firefox/Chrome/IE/... browser?)